# Clicking desired pixels - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that clicks the specified Colors on the screen (RGB). I know how to get the colors from the pixel by position. I'm using the Robot class but it doesn't have a built in method to do what I want. What can I use to do this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to do a screen capture:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle)
```

Then process the image to find your pixel:

```
// the color you want to find
// Set it to your desired value
Color myColorToMatch = new Color();
int w = bufferedImage.getWidth(null);
int h = bufferedImage.getHeight(null);
// find your pixel in the rgbs array
for(int y=0;y<h;y++) {
 for(int x=0;x<w;x++) {
  int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
  Color currentColor = new Color(pixel);

  if(currentColor.equals(myColorToMatch)) {
   robot.mouseMove(x, y);
   robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
   robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
  }
 }
}
```

Note: this is untested code but mostly gives you all parts needed.